# GSMComm phoneConnected/phoneDisconnected Handlers

Tags: c#, gsm

Trying to develop small application using GsmComm Library.
At the moment a have some problems with detecting if phone is connected or no.

it's detects when phone is disconnected, but doesn't want to detect phone  when is connected back again ...

Any idea why ?

my code:

```
        GsmCommMain gsm = new GsmCommMain(4, 115200, 200);



private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gsm.PhoneConnected += new EventHandler(gsmPhoneConnected);
                gsm.PhoneDisconnected += new EventHandler(gsmPhoneDisconnected);
                gsm.Open();
        }

private delegate void ConnctedHandler(bool connected);

    private void onPhoneConnectedChange(bool connected)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connected)
            {

                phoneStatus.Text = "OK";
            }
            else
            {
                phoneStatus.Text = "NG";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exce)
        {
            logBox.Text += "\n\r" + exce.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void gsmPhoneConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new ConnctedHandler(onPhoneConnectedChange), new object[] { true });
    }

    private void gsmPhoneDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new ConnctedHandler(onPhoneConnectedChange), new object[] { false });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer. Just noticed your question.
There is no need to use EventHandler for connection. If you want to call some functions after phone/gsm modem is connected you should call them after you opened port and (!) checked whether connection is established using **IsConnected()** member function in *GsmCommMain* class.

```
var gsm = new GsmCommMain(4, 115200, 200);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //gsm.PhoneConnected += new EventHandler(gsmPhoneConnected);   // not needed..
    gsm.PhoneDisconnected += new EventHandler(gsmPhoneDisconnected);
    gsm.Open();
    if(gsm.IsConnected()){
        this.onPhoneConnectedChange(true);
    }
}

private delegate void ConnctedHandler(bool connected);
private void onPhoneConnectedChange(bool connected)
{
    try
    {
        if (connected)
        {

            phoneStatus.Text = "OK";
        }
        else
        {
            phoneStatus.Text = "NG";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exce)
    {
        logBox.Text += "\n\r" + exce.ToString();
    }
}

/*public void gsmPhoneConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new ConnctedHandler(onPhoneConnectedChange), new object[] { true });
}*/

private void gsmPhoneDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new ConnctedHandler(onPhoneConnectedChange), new object[] { false });
}
```